# Trying to get property of non-object Filename: views/galleries_pictures.php

Tags: codeigniter

I wonder how to fix this error messages?

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Trying to get property of non-object
>
> Filename: views/galleries_pictures.php
>
> Line Number: 69

models/Mpages.php

```
public function add_picture_gallery($filename, $gallery_id)
{   

    $data = array(
        'galleryies_id' => $gallery_id,
        'galleries_picture_name' => $filename,
    );

    $query = $this->db->insert('galleries_pictures', $data);
    return $query->result();

}
```

HTML

```
<tr>                                
    <td><img src="<?php echo base_url();?>uploads/<?php echo $pictures_item->galleries_picture_name; ?>" height="200" width="300"></td>
    <td><?php echo $pictures_item->galleries_picture_name; ?></td>
    <td><button type="button" class="edit">EDIT</button></td>
    <td><button type="button" class="delete">DELETE</button></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Is $gallery_id and $filename not null always? @DavyYG

Comment: Yes, they never be null

Comment: Which is line number 69? @DavyYG

Comment: Line 69:       <td><img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>uploads/<?php echo $pictures_item->galleries_picture_name; ?>" height="200" width="300"></td>

Comment: So your $picture_item does not have galleries_picture_name that's why it is throwing error. @DavyYG

Comment: If I change it to $pictures_item['galleries_picture_name']; /  It start throwing another error :  Message: Undefined index: galleries_picture_name / I thought it suppose to contain galleries_picture_name I check the model.  /  It is strange

Comment: Just print_r($pictures_item) and show me the output. @DavyYG

Comment: Array ( [galleries_id] => 2 [galleries_name] => gallery1 )

Comment: Ohh! Got it! It should be $pictures_item['galleries_name'] not galleries_picture_name. @DavyYG

Comment: What are you trying to achieve first you can not use `return result` in insert it only `returns true or false` same as update

Answer (score 0):

First you need to `select`. not `insert`

**Try this way.**

in Controller

```
$data['image_list'] = $this->ur_Model->get_image_list();
$this->load->view('ur_view_filename', $data);
```

in Model

```
public function get_image_list()
  {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('ur_table');    
    return $this->db->get();
  }
```

in View

```
<table>
  <?php foreach ($image_list->result() as $pictures_item) { ?>
    <tr>                              
      <td><img src="<?php echo base_url();?>uploads/<?php echo $pictures_item->galleries_picture_name; ?>" height="200" width="300"></td>
      <td><?php echo $pictures_item->galleries_picture_name; ?></td>
      <td><button type="button" class="edit">EDIT</button></td>
      <td><button type="button" class="delete">DELETE</button></td>
    </tr>
  <?php } ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Why select?  I thouht I would like to insert new data.

Comment: I thought you were trying to display images. 
If insert, not need to `return $query->result()` just `return $query`; 
`result()` object is meant for while selecting from tables.